# How to import csv file data to postgresql in "omnidb" in windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, csv

I am using this command to import csv file data to postgresql in **omnidb windows** :

```
COPY owner."order"(id,type,name) 
FROM 'C:\Users\Desktop\omnidb_exported.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

Getting this error, although it exists:

> could not open file "C:\Users\Desktop\omnidb_exported.csv" for
>   reading: No such file or directory

I have also provided everyone security permissions of read and execute on csv file and its folder. Still the problem exists.

The csv file has delimiter ";" with header information.
This owner schema has 3 tables, which are connected by "id" column.

How to import the csv file data correctly? What is the problem with these commands?

Answer (score 1):

OK, as below:

```
\copy owner."order"(id,type,name) FROM 'C:\Users\Desktop\omnidb_exported.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

Just replace the `copy` to `\copy`, then can load data sucessfully.

Comment: @Sophia reEdited, try agian.

Comment: I am still getting the error: `syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \copy owner."order"`

Comment: But even if I work in psql query tool, it gives same type of error! @Shawn.X

Comment: All right, I tested in my linux system, `\copy` would work well.